# Optimization of iteration in R

Tags: r, if-statement, optimization

Preface: I do have two csv-tables each containing 3 million rows and about 20 columns and I want to extract 5 columns for all rows which meet certain requirements. It would be better if I worked with SQL or some other data base tool, but hey, I started out in R! and I do have to finish it now.

Currently my request is running on a R!-server with about 16 GB RAM - tomorrow the run of the first table will hit one week runtime and about 80% are done.

This leads me to following question: Does it make any difference how I formulate my if-clause? Currently I do the following (omitting loading csv, preparing dataframe etc):

```
i = 1
while(i < length_csv){
   if((csv$column11[i] != condition1) && (csv$column11[i] != condition2) 
   && (csv$column11[i] != condition3) && (csv$column11[i] != condition4) 
   && (csv$column11[i] != condition5) && (csv$column11[i] != condition6) 
   && (csv$column11[i] != condition7) && (csv$column3[i] == condition8)){
      dataframe = rbind(dataframe,c(csv$column1[i],csv$column2[i],csv$column11[i],csv$column12[i],csv$column13[i]))
      }
   i = i + 1
}
```

Would it be more efficient if the request was nested like

```
i = i+1
while(i < length_csv){
    if(csv$column3[i] == condition8){
        if(csv$column11[i] != condition1){
            if(csv$column11[i] != condition2){
                ... etc 
                }
    }
}
```

Or are there other ways to formulate the request I might have overlooked?

Comment: Erik, this is a clear example of (1) a clear moment when using vectorized operations instead of `while` or `for` loops will likely improve performance considerably; (2) doing repeated `rbind` like this works fine for low counts and scales *horribly*; and (3) we would benefit from a slightly better example, including a *small sample* of data.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for some methods of providing relevant (but not gargantuan) sample data.

Comment: Is it save to assume that `csv$row11` and `csv$row3` are truly *columns* in the data? Though the code is clearly accessing columns, the `row` in the name is a bit ... off ...

Comment: @r2evans: Since I so far only worked with small data counts, I didn't know about the scaling thing, thanks. Also, yes, row = column, I'll edit this in a second. And no, I sadly cannot provide a sample of the data, since I only got it in context of my thesis and am not allowed to spread it. Otherwise I would have done so.

Comment: It saddens me that you've been waiting a week for something that should take seconds (or at most minutes, depending on your data and conditionals).

Comment: BTW: "small sample of data" can mean "small *representative* example data", not always a sampling of your actual data (though that is often helpful/necessary, it is not here). I understand and respect that some data is either PII-encumbered, proprietary, or something else. Realize though that questions of "how do I do this" when we have no idea what "this" is become onerous and difficult to answer. Fake data suffices for concepts.

Comment: ... and almost every time I've had to create fake representative data, the act of reducing the data down to the problem area has *always* helped me think more about what really needs to be done. It usually helps me to solve my own question but invariably helps me produce more generic and elegant code. (I can't tell you how many questions I've started on SO and, while reducing data and code, resolved my own question. Learning that process is very *very* helpful to learning/improving programming styles.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever possible, I suggest you *avoid* `for` loops and repeated `rbind` for filtering your data. Using some sample data:

```
set.seed(2)
n <- 1e4
df <- data.frame(
  row11 = sample(100, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  row3 = sample(100, size=n, replace=TRUE)
)
dim(df)
# [1] 10000     2
head(df)
#   row11 row3
# 1    19    5
# 2    71   27
# 3    58   31
# 4    17   52
# 5    95   37
# 6    95   79
```

### Vectorize It!

```
cond1 <- df$row11 > 30
cond2 <- df$row11 < 40
cond3 <- df$row3 > 10
cond4 <- df$row3 < 15
str(cond1)
#  logi [1:10000] FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
out1 <- df[ cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4, ]
str(out1)
# 'data.frame': 31 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ row11: int  39 35 37 33 37 36 32 34 32 37 ...
#  $ row3 : int  13 11 14 13 11 13 14 12 11 12 ...
```

(The use of `cond1`, et al, as predefined `logical` vectors is completely optional. This works just as well with literal conditionals inside the `[...]` brackets. Additionally, I know that your data has more columns ... this works just fine with more columns.)

To see the benefit of using the vectorized approach over loops (either literal `for` or using `lapply` in a similar fashion):

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  vec = {
    cond1 <- df$row11 > 30
    cond2 <- df$row11 < 40
    cond3 <- df$row3 > 10
    cond4 <- df$row3 < 15
    df[ cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4, ]
  },
  forloop = {
    out2 <- df[0,]
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
      if (df$row11[i] > 30 && df$row11[i] < 40 &&
            df$row3[i] > 10 && df$row3[i] < 15) {
        out2 <- rbind(out2, df[i,,drop=FALSE])
      }
    }
  },
  lapp = {
    out3 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) {
      if (df$row11[i] > 30 && df$row11[i] < 40 &&
            df$row3[i] > 10 && df$row3[i] < 15) {
        df[i,,drop=FALSE]
      }
    })
    do.call(rbind, out3)
  }
)
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
#      vec    340.605    381.813    444.9889    409.1635    476.2635    758.519   100
#  forloop 142056.061 154749.407 169612.1311 165602.7955 178100.6755 254283.720   100
#     lapp 148903.885 161126.073 178910.3185 172380.4195 186945.8120 256529.009   100
```

That this means is that what I did in around 409μsec, the `for` and `lapply` implementations were *three orders of magnitude* higher.

### Much Larger Data

For a demonstration closer to your data-size:

```
set.seed(2)
# 3 million rows
nr <- 3e6
# 20 columns
nc <- 20
df <- as.data.frame(setNames(lapply(seq_len(nc), function(i) sample(100, size=nr, replace=TRUE)),
                             paste0("row", seq_len(nc))))
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 3000000 obs. of  20 variables:
#  $ row1 : int  19 71 58 17 95 95 13 84 47 55 ...
#  $ row2 : int  55 86 45 12 20 4 53 53 9 56 ...
#  $ row3 : int  78 100 93 86 67 61 45 41 82 32 ...
#  $ row4 : int  2 8 71 33 10 61 84 6 12 72 ...
#  $ row5 : int  31 27 32 75 100 54 80 2 52 10 ...
#  $ row6 : int  35 84 37 100 61 27 8 89 18 69 ...
#  $ row7 : int  100 28 54 34 18 68 25 96 8 9 ...
#  $ row8 : int  47 4 50 4 46 34 64 88 17 73 ...
#  $ row9 : int  45 91 13 1 78 17 40 78 81 39 ...
#  $ row10: int  31 41 87 60 30 30 22 99 85 44 ...
#  $ row11: int  83 90 10 51 88 27 21 48 87 27 ...
#  $ row12: int  94 83 44 53 58 41 39 5 93 6 ...
#  $ row13: int  65 90 8 55 85 100 14 41 44 99 ...
#  $ row14: int  39 29 18 32 87 80 32 62 22 12 ...
#  $ row15: int  33 15 58 46 7 4 61 35 32 60 ...
#  $ row16: int  22 17 58 27 24 56 83 59 22 44 ...
#  $ row17: int  38 28 7 40 95 21 13 53 78 64 ...
#  $ row18: int  64 12 88 55 36 68 84 16 82 15 ...
#  $ row19: int  48 53 75 62 61 31 36 23 4 18 ...
#  $ row20: int  25 89 1 11 10 40 24 50 50 66 ...

system.time({
  cond1 <- df$row11 > 30
  cond2 <- df$row11 < 40
  cond3 <- df$row3 > 10
  cond4 <- df$row3 < 15
  out1 <- df[ cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4, ]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.14    0.04    0.18
```

Reducing 3M rows to just over 10K in well under 1 second:

```
str(out1)
# 'data.frame': 10685 obs. of  20 variables:
#  $ row1 : int  47 82 31 1 10 86 97 85 74 56 ...
#  $ row2 : int  42 5 48 1 48 10 11 18 11 94 ...
#  $ row3 : int  13 12 11 12 13 12 12 11 14 11 ...
#  $ row4 : int  75 29 66 53 21 2 78 52 39 87 ...
#  $ row5 : int  69 90 27 67 96 23 1 36 70 83 ...
#  $ row6 : int  95 77 34 99 26 63 78 100 23 42 ...
#  $ row7 : int  23 27 95 61 58 91 36 35 35 35 ...
#  $ row8 : int  57 92 47 23 69 49 1 44 29 99 ...
#  $ row9 : int  49 17 44 65 10 94 76 60 74 81 ...
#  $ row10: int  85 86 77 76 54 29 12 14 87 68 ...
#  $ row11: int  34 31 34 34 37 31 32 37 31 37 ...
#  $ row12: int  15 69 35 53 92 67 47 73 66 55 ...
#  $ row13: int  66 57 78 8 2 14 31 88 46 67 ...
#  $ row14: int  41 83 28 47 98 61 79 93 35 79 ...
#  $ row15: int  36 37 15 12 18 62 25 64 15 98 ...
#  $ row16: int  72 60 93 31 27 84 37 78 34 76 ...
#  $ row17: int  83 2 48 20 92 25 6 57 55 66 ...
#  $ row18: int  45 88 86 71 92 27 20 82 89 43 ...
#  $ row19: int  9 34 79 9 28 39 37 72 90 14 ...
#  $ row20: int  59 3 44 35 65 54 41 50 87 18 ...
```

Comment: (I'm rather perplexed, by the way, why the `lapply` implementation performed *worse* than the `for` loop, particularly because of the inefficiency of `rbind`ing millions of times vice once. It *should* be slightly faster, in my eyes.)

Comment: Sorry for the belated answer, I had to work a lot. I just took some time to get into your code and will apply it to my data tomorrow, but so far this looks both awesome and awesomely short and I am very grateful for you sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Well, I'm gonna go cry in a ditch somewhere. Your vectorized approach took shocking 4 seconds to finish. Thank you very much, I'll make sure to credit you or at least stack in my thesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code avoiding the use of "rbind" on each step of your iteration. You should avoid growing your object (pre-allocate if possible) and use vectorized operations. You could try something like this (not tested since a representative example of the data is not provided):

```
tst <- lapply(1:length_csv, function(i) {
  if((csv$row11[i] != condition1) && (csv$row11[i] != condition2) 
     && (csv$row11[i] != condition3) && (csv$row11[i] != condition4) 
     && (csv$row11[i] != condition5) && (csv$row11[i] != condition6) 
     && (csv$row11[i] != condition7) && (csv$row3[i] == condition8)) {
     out <- csv$row11[i]
     return(out)
  }

})

dataframe <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, tst))
```