# Give a data.frame an index per value of another column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with a layout like this:

```
Data =    Id somevalue
          1   ab
          1   cd
          1   i
          2   o
          2   j
```

And I want to get index it by the Id such that i get the following:

```
Data =    Id somevalue index
          1   ab        1
          1   cd        2
          1   i         3
          2   o         1
          2   j         2
```

The way I do it now is with

```
for(ID in search_IDs)
{
   Data[Data[,1]==ID,]$index<-1:length(Data[DataGuess[,1]==ID,1])   
}
```

or more r like:

```
Data<-as.data.frame(sapply(Ids,FUN=(function(x,y)y[y[,1]==x,]$index<-1:length(y[y[,1]==x,1])),y=Data))
```

However both take a long time to finish and I was wondering if there was a faster way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R:

```
x1 <- do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  by(x, x$Id, function(df) { df$index <- seq_len(nrow(df)); df; })
)
x1
#     Id somevalue index
# 1.1  1        ab     1
# 1.2  1        cd     2
# 1.3  1         i     3
# 2.4  2         o     1
# 2.5  2         j     2
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x2 <- x %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
x2
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#      Id somevalue index
#   <int> <chr>     <int>
# 1     1 ab            1
# 2     1 cd            2
# 3     1 i             3
# 4     2 o             1
# 5     2 j             2
```

---

Your data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
Id somevalue
1   ab
1   cd
1   i
2   o
2   j')
```

Comment: Thanks, from 1.4 min to 0.7 seconds is quite the improvement

Comment: I've seen better -- one problem decreased from [1 week runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48627757/3358272) to [4 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627757/optimization-of-iteration-in-r/48629299#comment84424587_48629299). :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  somevalue = c('ab', 'cd', 'i', 'o', 'j')
)

d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(index = 1) %>%
  mutate(index = cumsum(index))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id somevalue index
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 ab            1
#> 2     1 cd            2
#> 3     1 i             3
#> 4     2 o             1
#> 5     2 j             2
```